# country_select not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering this code from a partial:

```
<%= f.country_select :country_code, {object: f.object, prompt: "Country"}, required: true %>
```

And my country code isn't saving to the database. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep points to just make a comment, but did you add country_code to the controller_params in controller?

And also, should it be nested and added to permitted _params?

Comment: DUH. Too soon. Thanks!